# Does life need to start in water, or can life generate on land, or perhaps in air?

Tags: science-based, abiogenesis

Is it possible that life could come about on land if a planet has a dense atmosphere? (This applies to non-carbon based life as well).

Comment: By land, do you mean "dry land", or a puddle of water is Ok?

Comment: I'm reminded of the [Urey-Miller Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment) which I think @Alexander may have been getting at. Water is really useful for chemistry, but the atmosphere can still play a role. It depends on if by water you mean "in a hydrothermal ocean environment."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Life *can* form on land (or in the air), but it will most likely form in water first.**

If life is going to spontaneously form from a complex soup of inorganic compounds at all, then it will likely form early on in a planet's capacity to support such life. Based on our current knowledge, that means that it's likely going to first form in water. There are several reasons for this;

- Water means that the chemicals are mobile, floating in currents, and more likely to 'mix' with their necessary counterparts to form life
- Water also protects reasonably well from cosmic rays, meaning that the life that forms, being new and fragile, doesn't get immediately irradiated and therefore destroyed immediately after forming
- Water is a good thermal mass, meaning that life is protected from the extremes of temperature variation even in a day and night cycle (deserts get very cold at night as well as very hot during the day)
- Liquid water is needed for life as we currently understand it anyway, so even if it formed on land it's not going to be far away from a water source if it forms there.

All that said; if you had a thick atmosphere, and the complex chemicals were tossed around by the wind cycles of the atmosphere which also contained a lot of water vapour and had an ozone layer and magnetic field already well established to protect from cosmic rays, it's *possible* that life could form outside of water, but less likely. If abiogenesis is going to occur and it's more or less random when and where, the opportunity for it to happen and take hold is more probable in water than it is on land or in the atmosphere, for all the reasons above.

The trouble with the statement above however is the ozone layer - ozone is a naturally occurring molecule (O<sub>3</sub>) that is generated in our atmosphere as a result of sunlight on an oxygen rich atmosphere. The reason why this is an issue is because life is unlikely to spawn in an already oxygen rich atmosphere because oxygen reacts with many other elements like carbon and iron meaning that it gets stripped out of the atmosphere really quickly by natural processes. The reason why we have an oxygen rich environment is because of the Great Oxygenation Event and the fact that (to play it safe) plants produce more oxygen than they need for their own metabolism, just in case the sun is covered by clouds or because of winter, etc. in terms of reduced output. So, life could only form on land on a planet that is already rich in oxygen in the atmosphere, with one exception.

If you had a large amount of water vapour in the upper atmosphere of your planet, a water canopy if you will, you could protect your new land based life from cosmic rays through this water canopy until you had your own Great Oxygenation Event occur. The water canopy would likely dissipate over time, increasing sea levels but allowing the ozone layer to take over.

Either way, it is still more likely that life will form in the oceans of your planet on balance of probability, but under some exotic setups, it is possible that it could form in a different location.